# Bitcoin disappeared from wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Someone sent money to my wallet. It arrived but then disappeared from my wallet.

When I checked on https://blockchain.info, they wrote that it arrived but was pruned from their database.

What does this mean?

Comment: Please add the transaction ID to the question. If you don't know the transaction ID, state the address the money was sent to.

Comment: Mind attaching a screenshot of their email? It's very weird that a transaction would be pruned from their database.

Comment: "they wrote that it arrived but was pruned from their database." ← Where did you see this message? In your wallet or in the blockexplorer? Do you perhaps mean that there was an unconfirmed transaction they showed you and later that transaction became replaced?